# Get Partial Url from Uri

Tags: c#, .net, uri

```
 Uri url = new Uri("http://www.website.com/content/a/?filter=porn");
```

Is there any way only get a string with "/content/a/" from the Uri?
I mean no domain or query string parameters without having to work with strings?

Comment: The part of uri you are looking for called "path". Duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/830755/asp-net-vb-net-getting-the-path-from-the-url-uri shows usage of `AbsolutePath` as well notes other path-related functions if you need to extract file name later.

Comment: After re-reading what I thought is duplicate it is not - it actually asks how to parse path unlike this question about "does `Uri` class have property that returns path of the uri". This question needs some edits clarify why reading of list of properties of `Uri` class is not enough (likely the goal is not just `AbsolutePath`, but it is unclear from current version).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not sure why @AlexK deleted his answer, but `url.AbsolutePath` will give you that info.

```
Uri url = new Uri("http://www.website.com/content/a/?filter=porn");
Console.WriteLine(url.AbsolutePath);   
// outputs /content/a
```

https://dotnetfiddle.net/3koJ7v

Comment: I deleted after realising that it would also include a file name if one were present

Comment: Oh I see. Well, the OP hasn't asked that so we're not sure whether he wants/ doesn't want that. Your answer would still be correct technically then. As a courtesy or if the OP modifies his question, you could always improvise your answer!